# Sources for claims about the identity of Kitty, the addressee of Anne Frank's diary entries

Tags: dutch-language, anne-frank, the-diary-of-a-young-girl

Anne Frank addressed her diary entries to Kitty and there has been much conjecture whether this name referred to a real person or was inspired by one. The English Wikipedia article about [*The Diary of Young Girl*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=The_Diary_of_a_Young_Girl&oldid=971638809) contains the following sequence of unsourced statements about the identity of Kitty:

> Theodor Holman wrote in reply to Sietse van der Hoek that the diary entry for 28 September 1942 proved conclusively the character's fictional origin.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> Jacqueline van Maarsen agreed,<sup>[citation needed]</sup> but Otto Frank assumed his daughter had her real acquaintance in mind when she wrote to someone of the same name.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

The [German Wikipedia article about Anne Frank's diary](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tagebuch_der_Anne_Frank&oldid=202378129#Form_und_Inhalt) also discusses Kitty's identity but omits the unsourced statements. The [Dutch Wikipedia article](https://nl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Het_Achterhuis_(dagboek)&oldid=56806051) does not attempt to summarise the discussion about the identity of Kitty.

My question now is the following: what are the sources on which the claims by Theodor Holman, Jacqueline van Maarsen and Otto Frank are presumably based?